# Motion Tracking. Why is my solve error so high?

Tags: camera, tracking

When i track my points (Black dots on white paper) it looks pretty good yet my solve error comes out to about 12.5. Please help me out

Comment: Check the curves of the tracks, maybe upload a sceenshot. You'll see the failing trackingpoints there. (spikes)

Comment: Have you set your camera information like focal length and sensor size correctly?

Comment: read through the information on this link: [How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332) pay special attention on items 2 through 6